# FBGraph Api Fails due to OAuthException. How to solve this?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, facebook-graph-api, ios7

FBGrah api call fails to load the login page of Facebook & here is the error message I got it on screen:
[image]

Below is code that I have used to create FBGraph Objetc:

```
NSString *client_id = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];


            [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access" andSuperView:self.view];
```

Suggest me how to solve this issue.

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: @Nitesh please check now, added code to my query

Comment: try Autheticating this way                                   
     
    [FBSession    openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"email",@"friends_birthday"]
         allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
            
             AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
             sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
             [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
         }];